# Which scope has a static variable?

Tags: c++, static

I am writing a simple program which has few settings. The settings are static variables defined in a `config.h` header file.

For example, inside `config.h`:

```
static int setting1 = 10 ;
```

In another file, `kkk.cpp`, I have a function which changes the value of `setting1`:

```
void classA::functionA()
{
    setting1=5;
    classB.functionB();
}
```

However, in the `classB.functionB`, which is defined under file `eee.cpp`

```
void classB::functionB()
{
    int hh=setting1;
    printf("%d",hh);
}
```

`hh` is still the old value of `setting1` (`setting1 == 10`).

Although the `setting1` is a global static, its value cannot be changed? Why?

Comment: Why do you use a `static` (=internal linkage) global when a normal global variable + `extern` would do the trick?

Comment: `setting1` is *not* a global static; there is no such thing.  Inherently, the scope of a `static` variable is limited to at most the TU (translation unit) in which it is defined; sometimes, the scope is smaller.

Answer (score 6):

If you declare a namespace-scope variable as `static` in a header file and then include that header file in multiple source files, there will be one instance of that variable per source file in which it is included.  A `static` namespace-scope variable has internal linkage.

You have a few options:

- Declare the variable in one of the .cpp files
- Declare the variable as `extern` in the header file and then define it in only one of the .cpp files
- Use a static member variable and define it in one .cpp file

Comment: By C-Standard a global variable defined as static is like anti-extern. To the linker: extern = Don't worry; you'll find this declared in another c (obj) file.  static = Even if somebody else put this same variable name in their C file too; this isn't that one.